# ways for creating interfaces for external classes decorators

Tags: java, android, oop, interface, decorator

I have 2 different classes with almost identical functionality but from very different libs:

```
java.awt.Canvas
```

and

```
android.graphics.Canvas
```

I wonder if there exist some well-known approach for creating an interface for decorators for external classes.

Particularly, I want to create an interface that will be used for implementing within my app's Canvasable classes and I will have intermadiate classes (they called as decorators i guess) that will manage with Canvas from other libs. I guess that I need extract interfaces from external classes and make comparison of that, and the decide what should be included into my interface. Is there exist some best practice for such task?

Beside particular case any conceptual advises are appreciated, tanks!

Comment: High level what are you trying to do? Why are you using both the swing and Android canvas?

Comment: I am thinking about wrapping of existing awt-based lib for Android

Comment: More precisely, i want to abstract drawing operations because I suppose that my lib may be used not only on Android but with swing as well